# Short form of word "available"

Tags: abbreviations, shorthand

Is there a *short form* for word **Available** as in *qty* for **Quantity**? I do not even think that "short from" is the right word for what I'm after. If that's so then what is this form called? Shorthand maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: The only abbreviation for 'Available' that I would instantly recognise correctly in all contexts is "Avail."

Comment: 'In stock' is often used (1 character less too!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you "AVBL".

On [this website](http://www.allacronyms.com/available/abbreviatedwebsite) you can find a list of abbreviation.

**Edit: Short forms copied from the mentioned website**

**AVBL** Available
*Technology*

**Avail** Available
*Technology, Aviation*

**AVL** Available
*Business, Real Estate, Real estate jargon*

**AV** Available
*Technology, Telecom, Telecommunications*

**AVAIL.** Available
*Business, Property, Property rent*

Comment: Why should this website be trusted ? Not all information on the Internet is reliable.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary are you talking about http://english.stackexchange.com? if yes then this could be a good question for http://meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, no. I was talking about the website Bastien Rouiller quoted. (allacronyms.com)

Answer (score 2):

Is there a *short form* for [the] word Available as in qty for Quantity?

No, there is no established abbreviation for "available" like "qty", however depending on the context of whatever you're writing, you could probably use Av (for Available) and NA (for Not Available - it also means Not Applicable).